# Multiple histograms in Julia using Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am working with a large number of observations and to really get to know it I want to do histograms using Plots.jl
My question is how I can do multiple histograms in one plot as this would be really handy. I have tried multiple things already, but I am a bit confused with the different plotting sources in julia (plots.jl, pyplot, gadfly,...).

I don't know if it would help for me to post some of my code, as this is a more general question. But I am happy to post it, if needed.

Comment: Do you mean to have multiple histograms overlayed or to have subplots?

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. I would like to have multiple histograms overlaid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [an example](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/ExamplePlots.jl/blob/master/notebooks/scratch/hist.ipynb) that does just this:

```
using Plots
pyplot()

n = 100
x1, x2 = rand(n), 3rand(n)

# see issue #186... this is the standard histogram call
# our goal is to use the same edges for both series
histogram(Any[x1, x2], line=(3,0.2,:green), fillcolor=[:red :black], fillalpha=0.2)
```

I looked for "histograms" in [the Plots.jl repo](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/search?q=histograms&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93), found [this related issue](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/319) and followed [the](https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl/issues/254#issuecomment-218760020) [links](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/186) to the example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry, still very new to this ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `Plots`, there are two possibilities to show multiple series in one plot:

First, you can use a matrix, where each column constitutes a separate series:

```
a, b, c = randn(100), randn(100), randn(100)
histogram([a b c])
```

Here, `hcat` is used to concatenate the vectors (note the spaces instead of commas).

This is equivalent to

```
histogram(randn(100,3))
```

You can apply options to the individual series using a **row matrix**:

```
histogram([a b c], label = ["a" "b" "c"])
```

(Again, note the spaces instead of commas)

Second, you can use `plot!` and its variants to update a previous plot:

```
histogram(a)  # creates a new plot
histogram!(b) # updates the previous plot
histogram!(c) # updates the previous plot
```

Alternatively, you can specify which plot to update:

```
p = histogram(a) # creates a new plot p
histogram(b)     # creates an independent new plot
histogram!(p, c) # updates plot p
```

This is useful if you have several subplots.

**Edit:**

Following Felipe Lema's links, you can implement a recipe for histograms that share the edges:

```
using StatsBase
using PlotRecipes

function calcbins(a, bins::Integer)
    lo, hi = extrema(a)
    StatsBase.histrange(lo, hi, bins) # nice edges
end

calcbins(a, bins::AbstractVector) = bins

@userplot GroupHist 

@recipe function f(h::GroupHist; bins = 30)
    args = h.args
    length(args) == 1 || error("GroupHist should be given one argument")
    bins = calcbins(args[1], bins)
    seriestype := :bar
    bins, mapslices(col -> fit(Histogram, col, bins).weights, args[1], 1)
end

grouphist(randn(100,3))
```

**Edit 2:**

Because it is faster, I changed the recipe to use `StatsBase.fit` for creating the histogram.